What is the impressed current density?

I don't have a too solid background for physics and am reading some engineering books of electromagnetics. What is the impressed current density here? I think it is Ohm's law but couldn't find its definition online (they are all $J = \sigma E$).

$\mathbf{J}_e$ is the "impressed current density" in the source/external battery, etc. (Ohm's law  need not hold in the source, so in the general discussion, there is a reason not to express it using conductivity $\sigma$).
It is contributing the total current density.
Also try not to read advanced eng E&M without any background in E&M it's just not gonna do any good.
